# How to know if JWT tokens are used as intended?

Tags: node.js, jwt

I would like to implement JWT based authentication in our new REST API. I wanted to ask if you define the purpose (access or refresh) of the received token from the client? Some applications do not have such a definition in jwt payloads.

```
{
  "id": "0123456789",
  "email": "some.email@gmail.com",
  "iat": 1687082137,
  "exp": 1687083937
}
```

Their access and refresh tokens looks like same except iat and exp.
How do they know if I use the old(but not expired yet) refresh token as an access token?

What is the best practice or solution of defining purpose of tokens?